# apache spark - delay on driver

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am attaching image from spark UI, and i am asking what is causing the delay( represented by white space) based on the description of my code below[image]

Description:

1) isEmpt: is a action triggered on a Dataset DS1. it takes fe milliseconds : 60ms.

2) The white space between "isEmpty" and " run at ThreadPool...".

3) "collect at graphUtil" : collection of Datasets created between 1) and 2)

The script is running on yarn cluster.

Between 1) and 2) i am declaring Datasets which uses sqlContext.implicits._, i am not collecting them here.so this is supposed to be work on Driver.Those Datasets contains Join/filter/....

Having that i am not collecting them between 1) and 2) what could be causing this delay.

Code between 1) and 2)

import sqlContext.implicits._

```
val intermediateInputFlowsIdsDS= intermediateInputFlowsDS
  .map(x=>x.flow)
  .toDF("flowid").distinct().as[Int].repartition($"flowid")

val df_exch_flow_interm_out=df_exch_flow.filter(df_exch_flow("flow_type")==="PRODUCT_FLOW"
  &&df_exch_flow("is_input")==="0" )

val allproducersExchDS= intermediateInputFlowsIdsDS.join(df_exch_flow_interm_out,
  intermediateInputFlowsIdsDS("flowid")===df_exch_flow_interm_out("f_flow") )
  .repartition($"f_owner")

//proc{id,name,proctype}/inter{flowid}/df_exch{exch,proc,flow,direct,amount,provider,unit}/df_flow{id,name,type}/unit{id,src,factor,dest}

  df_proc.join(allproducersExchDS,df_proc("Id")=== allproducersExchDS("f_owner"))
    .map(row => {

      /*(flowid,procid,value)*/
      new FlowProducer( row.getInt(3),// flowid output of producer
        row.getInt(0) ,// the process id of producer
        row.getDouble(8),// value of the matrix A cell,
        row.getDouble(16),//factor
        row.getString(17),//destination unit
        row.getString(2)//process type
      )

    }).repartition($"producer_flow")
```

Comment: Are you running this locally? On a cluster? Might some other process interfere? Is it like this everytime you run this?

Comment: @LiMuBei: yes every time . on cluster.

Comment: you need to look at GC activity

Comment: Eliasah: i will check GC even though  this is allways happening at the same place. The picture you see above is a fragment of a periodic cycle. Can you spot anything in my code that can cause the delay. could it be creating the datasets or importing implicits?

Comment: What is the threadpoolexecutor why i hVe It. I disnt created this. Any idea?